# How to automatically increase/decrease font size of string to fill the label in gtk in C

Tags: c, fonts, gtk, label

I have a GTK3 application and UI which I have made in glade. UI consist of a MainWindow with 2 vertical box. 1st box has a label and 2nd box has a button. When button is pressed, program reads a string from a file and display it on the label. Now if the string is small, I need to increase its font size to completely fill the label. If the size of string is larger than the size of label then I need to decrease the font size to make it fit inside the label.

For this problem ,I am trying to make a logic something like below :

1. Get the size of the label in pixels (Height & Width)
2. Get the size of the string when placed inside the label (Height & Width)
3. Increase/decrease the font size to fit inside the label
4. Apply the font and display the string on the label

For 1st point, I can use: `gtk_widget_get_allocation();`. To increase/decrease font I can use : `pango_font_description_set_size()`. But what can I use for 2nd point.

Does the algorithm I am trying is correct and possible in gtk.? Is there any other way of automatically increasing and decreasing the font size to fill the label in gtk.?

Comment: You need to use cairo and a drawing area (e.g.) and do some math to get text_extents that fill the widgets allocated size.

Comment: @JoséFonte I thought pango would be great for this purpose. I will look out for cairo. Do you have any similar examples related to my problem.

Comment: Well, It's a mix of Pango and Cairo (and Pango-Cairo).

Comment: [Check this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750093/fit-line-to-width-with-pango-and-cairo-pycairo)

Comment: @JoséFonte Thanks for the link. I got the idea. But its a python code, I want it in C. I will look out for their equivalent in C.